# Regular expressions making scraper

Tags: regex

I want to make a scraper that grab all the `<a id href="">...</a>` elements from some website and the format of the elements is:

```
<a id href="/model.aspx?modelid=886874">Samsung Galaxy Note 4 SM-N910F</a>
```

And the thing that is changed all the time is the `?modelid=integer`. How do I make a regular expression for this?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is going to lead to sorrow down the road.  Use a proper HTML parser.  We can help point you to one if you tell us what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$re = "/<a[^\"]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\\/a>/mi";
$str = "<a id href=\"sjdkg\">...</a>\n<a id href=\"sjdkg\">.dg..</a>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);


$matches[1]; // for href
$matches[2]; // for innertext
var_dump($matches);
```

**output:**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '<a id href="sjdkg">...</a>' (length=26)
      1 => string '<a id href="sjdkg">.dg..</a>' (length=28)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'sjdkg' (length=5)
      1 => string 'sjdkg' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '...' (length=3)
      1 => string '.dg..' (length=5)
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE9bV5/4)

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you need: 
modelid\=\d\d\d\d\d\d\">(.*)</a>

[image: Regex screenshot]

[Regex Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/nX5xG2/1)